# API to print PDF label

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

Here I created a simple controller that returns a PDF label that's generated in my domain model. What bothers me is that I make mutations on my model in controller. Is that bad practice? Of course any other suggestions about the code are also more than welcome.

```
class Binary(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/web/binary/download_labels', type='http', auth="public")
    def download_labels(self, ids, **kw):
        ids = eval(ids)
        pickings = http.request.env['stock.picking'].browse(ids)
        carrier = pickings[0].carrier_id
        response = carrier.get_parcel_labels(pickings)
        filecontent = response.content
        if not filecontent:
            return request.not_found()
        else:
            filename = _('DPD_labels_%s.pdf') % fields.Date.today()
            # These two lines below bother me
            #  because I'm doing my business logic in controller, but shouldn't we do 
            #  our business logic only in the domain layer?
            for pick in pickings:
                pick.write({'dpd_register_date': fields.Date.today()})
            return request.make_response(
                filecontent, [
                    ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'),
                    ('Content-Disposition', content_disposition(filename))]
            )
```